# Set Background color from database

Tags: razor, styles

I want to add `background-color` from the database `"background-color:#333333"` this code I have written just for understanding color value will come from database.

This one is working Perfectly

```
 <font style="font-size:@BannerDesc.FontSize; font-family: @BannerDesc.FontName; color:@BannerDesc.FontColor">@BannerDesc.BannerDescription</font>
```

This is not working and dont know why

Try#1:

```
 Dim Style As String = "background-color:#333333"
    @<div class="ribbon-wrapper"><div class="ribbon" style="@Style">New</div></div>
    End If
```

Try#2:

```
 Dim Style As String = "#333333"
        @<div class="ribbon-wrapper"><div class="ribbon" style="background-color:@Style">New</div></div>
        End If
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: There is no error message when I inspect that `<div>` it shows me `<div class = "ribbon" style="">`. So it means style is not being applied its empty

Comment: I guess I solve it myself i forgot to put `;` i change to this `style="background-color:@Style;`. So does `;` makes any difference